# What regular expression engine is used by default in LoadRunner 11.52?

Tags: regex, loadrunner

I keep trying to find an online regular expression checker to use with web_reg_save_param_regexp but no joy.  What RegEx engine is LoadRunner 11.52 using?

It looks to be some variant of Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LoadRunner we use this: http://www.pcre.org/

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: That did the trick.  A search for 
online PCRE checker
found a list of regular expression checkers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.http503.com/2011/web_reg_save_param_regexp-a-regexp-primer-for-performance-testers/) suggests that the author is using http://rubular.com/ to test his web_reg_save_param_regexp, suggesting that it's likely PCRE (at least partly implemented).

A great PCRE checker is **http://regex101.com**.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I saw that article too. Regular expressions that pass Rebular fail in LoadRunner.  Rubular's failure was one reason why I asked my question.

Comment: Ah, I see. http://regex101.com is a great PCRE checker -- didn't realize that rubular was where the problem was ;)