# Regular Expression to represent multiple lines

Tags: c, regex, loadrunner

Is there a shorter way of representing the following bit of code using RegEx -

```
survey=fa3773ea26e64b7c8715fba9785b2486&plan=010">Survey X</a>\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td nowrap>&nbsp;READY FOR SUBMISSION
```

I have tried

```
survey=(.*?)&plan(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?);READY FOR SUBMISSION
```

While this has worked, I wanted to shorten the expression or make it more dynamic to make it capture any number of newline characters.

The bigger picture here is to search a web page for this pattern and capture the 'ready for submission' survey id using the 1st capture group. I am using the LoadRunner tool where we use C code.

Thank you.

*EDITORS NOTE: dot-matches-all is not an option.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
survey=([a-z\d]+)&plan(?:.|[\t\r\n])*?READY FOR SUBMISSION
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XsB8D9QPKoUWMj6O)

Comment: Thank you for your response. My dot-matching breaks at the newline character. And hence I had to put in those multiple instances of \n. I have added the language and tool information in the post. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You don't have the option to use dot-matches-all? Most regex flavors support this option, although I'm not familiar with C. Dot-matches-all  would mean a dot can also be used to match a new-line.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option for me. I have tested several times and seen the code to break at the newline.

Comment: Hmm... Updated with another try.

Comment: Wow that worked! I ended up using - `survey=(.*?)&plan(?:.|[\t\r\n])*?READY FOR SUBMISSION`. But, guess what, I got a STACK OVERFLOW error in the tool after the successful capture! Looking into the error. But, my capture problem is solved. Thanks much, @aliteralmind.

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410293/what-regular-expression-engine-is-used-by-default-in-loadrunner-11-52